# URLVariables not working in Haxe project

Tags: haxe, openfl, urlrequest, urlvariables

how are you doing? I hope fine.

So I'm trying to send an urlRequest and I can't pass the parameters by url so I'm trying to use the URLVariable, but no matter what I try my php always get null.

```
        var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest(SITE_DOMAIN + "/check_login.php");
        request.method = URLRequestMethod.POST; 
        var variables:URLVariables = new URLVariables();
        variables.login = emailInput.text;
        variables.password = senhaInput.text;
        variables.gotogame = "BURACO";
        Reflect.setField(variables, "login", emailInput.text);
        Reflect.setField(variables, "password", senhaInput.text);
        Reflect.setField(variables, "gotogame", "BURACO");
        request.data = variables;
        request.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
        openfl.Lib.getURL(request);
```

As you guys can see I'm trying to set the variables in two ways but neither of they are working and I kind of don't know what to do anymore, please help.

Answer (score 3):

Ive used this without problems:

```
    var request:Http = new Http(SERVER + "actions/layout-builder?random=" + Math.random());
    request.addParameter("action", "retrieve");
    request.addParameter("layoutId", layoutId);
    request.onError = function(msg) {
        showSimplePopup("Problem loading layout:\n\n" + msg);
    }
    request.onStatus = function(status:Int) {
    }
    request.onData = function(response) {
        response = StringTools.replace(response, "\r\n", "\n");
        layoutCode.text = response;
    }

    request.request(false);
```

Comment: I need this method of mine to open a new browser tab, is there a way to do that with this? Something like openfl.Lib.getURL(request);

Comment: Well i managed to make it work but only for windows, im running the project in html5 and the same codes that works for windows return me and error: html error #0